# How do I use htaccess to redirect multiple URLs of the same format to a new format?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect multiple URLs of the same format to a different format of URLs with one statement.

Original Format: http://example.com/blog/YYYY/MM/example-title/

where YYYY is a number from 2013 - 2017 and MM is a single OR double digit number between 1-12 OR 01-12 and example title can be any length, any letters, with dashes for spaces.

New Format: http://example.com/blog/example-title.php

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Is `/blog/` a real directory?

Comment: Yes it is. That directory is real and will be staying the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have this rule inside your `/blog/.htaccess` (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^\d+/\d+/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NE,R=301]

# other rules go here
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is interfering with the rules we have that create the blog post in the first place so it gave an error when I uploaded it. I think I might just redirect them all one at a time.

Comment: If you have existing rules in `/blog/.htaccess` then keep this rule as your very first rule. Also you need to clarify what problem you're fcing due to this rule.

Comment: It is actually a PHP error that would require us to do some reprogramming that we can not do right now, but thank you for the answer that I'm sure works in any other circumstance!